# AWK script. Pattern filtering problematic

Tags: awk

I have the following script:

```
cat trans_sop
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS="\t"
}

$8 !~ /^TR$/ {
    date = $2
    amount = $3
    item = $7
    type = $8
    year = substr(date, 1, 4)
    minYear = (NR == 1 || year < minYear ? year : minYear)
    maxYear = (NR == 1 || year > maxYear ? year : maxYear)
    cat = substr(type, 2)
    ctiys2amounts[cat][type][item][year] += amount
}

END {
    printf "DESCRIPTION"
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, year
    }
    print ORS
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc"
    for (cat in ctiys2amounts) {
        print ORS 
        printf "%s\n\n", (cat == "I") ? "INCOME" : "EXPENSES"
        delete catSum
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_desc"
        for (type in ctiys2amounts[cat]) {
            printf "%s\n", (type == "FI") ? "FIXED INCOME" : (type == "FE") ? "FIXED EXPENSES" : (type == "VI") ? "VARIABLE INCOME" : "VARIABLE EXPENSES"
            delete typeSum
            PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
            for (item in ctiys2amounts[cat][type]) {
                printf "%s", item
                for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                    amount = ctiys2amounts[cat][type][item][year]
                    printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, amount
                    typeSum[year] += amount
                }
                print ""
            }
            printf "TOTAL %s", (type == "FI") ? "FIXED INCOME" : (type == "FE") ? "FIXED EXPENSES" : (type == "VI") ? "VARIABLE INCOME" : "VARIABLE EXPENSES"
            for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
                printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, typeSum[year]
                catSum[year] += typeSum[year]
            }
            print ORS
        }
        #printf "sum%s", cat
        printf "%s", (cat == "I") ? "TOTAL INCOME" : "TOTAL EXPENSES"
        for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
            printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, catSum[year]
            yearSum[year] += catSum[year]
        }
        print ORS
    }
    print ORS
    printf "NET INCOME"
    for (year = minYear; year <= maxYear; year++) {
        printf "%s%0.2f", OFS, yearSum[year]
    }
    print ""
}

' "${@:--}"
```

`$8 !~ /^TR$/` in the 8th line does not work. It does not filter out rows with TR in column 8 and garbles the ouput. If however I modify the input file to this script to exclude those rows the script performs as expected. Why is this the case since the syntax seems alright? And what is the right way of doing this.
Here is some input data:

```
cat out1.txt 
j_wp_2  2017-12-01  100.00  From 0521-0003629-00    DIRECT CREDIT   15:22-12089 Transfers   TR
j_wp_3  2017-12-01  100.00  From 0502-0402122-00    DIRECT CREDIT   05:45-29600 Transfers   TR
j_wp_4  2017-12-01  -250.00 Edorne & Christian r    AUTOMATIC PAYMENT   Rent 3_146 C    Property – Rent FE
j_wp_5  2017-12-01  -200.00 Gem Finance AUTOMATIC PAYMENT   2023167391  Principal & Interest    FE
j_wp_6  2017-12-04  10.00   From 0521-0003629-00    DIRECT CREDIT   13:46-50567 Transfers   TR
j_wp_7  2017-12-04  50.00   From 0521-0003629-00    DIRECT CREDIT   12:34-37814 Transfers   TR
j_wp_8  2017-12-04  100.00  From 0521-0003629-00    DIRECT CREDIT   11:24-44869 Transfers   TR
j_wp_9  2017-12-04  100.00  From 0502-0402122-00    DIRECT CREDIT   11:24-66735 Transfers   TR
j_wp_10 2017-12-04  -97.90  Moore Wilsons   EFTPOS TRANSACTION  03-12:33-731    Household   VE
j_wp_11 2017-12-04  -194.98 Pak N Save Kilbirnie    EFTPOS TRANSACTION  03-13:46-693    Food – Groceries    VE
```

If I run it without `$8 !~ /^TR$/` I get the following output:

```
DESCRIPTION 2017



EXPENSES

VARIABLE EXPENSES
Transfers   460.00
TOTAL VARIABLE EXPENSES 460.00

TOTAL EXPENSES  460.00



EXPENSES

VARIABLE EXPENSES
Food – Groceries    -194.98
Household   -97.90
TOTAL VARIABLE EXPENSES -292.88

FIXED EXPENSES
Principal & Interest    -200.00
Property – Rent -250.00
TOTAL FIXED EXPENSES    -450.00

TOTAL EXPENSES  -742.88



NET INCOME  -282.88
```

The following should not be there after filtering out TR:

```
EXPENSES

VARIABLE EXPENSES
Transfers   460.00
TOTAL VARIABLE EXPENSES 460.00

TOTAL EXPENSES  460.00
```

Comment: Can you provide snippet of your input file?

Comment: Yes I have. Please see the update.

Comment: So it's easiest for us to help you, please create and post a [mcve] that demonstrates just the problem you're currently facing rather than posting all of your code within which somewhere is the relevant section. I'd guess that at least 80% of the code in your question is irrelevant to the actual problem you're having and so just making it harder to see the problem to help you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

> Here is some input data:

If I read that correctly `TR` does appear in 7th column as I parse 1st row

```
j_wp_2  2017-12-01  100.00  From 0521-0003629-00    DIRECT CREDIT   15:22-12089 Transfers   TR
```

as

- `j_wp_2` becomes `$1`
- `2017-12-01` becomes `$2`
- `100.0` becomes `$3`
- `From 0521-0003629-00` becomes `$4`
- `DIRECT CREDIT` becomes `$5`
- `15:22-12089 Transfers` becomes `$6`
- `TR` becomes `$7`

so you are probably referencing wrong field. To find if this is case, please subject your file to `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{print $8}'` and check if it does have `TR` in output - if not then this mean you are using wrong field.

Side note: You might use does not equal (`!=`) string rather than does not match (`!~`) regular expression, if you are interesting in rows where field is different. By doing this you do not have to care about characters with special meaning (e.g. dot) and anchors (`^` and `$`).
Imagine that you have COUNTRYCODE.CITY in 1st column and you are interesting in all records but Berlin (Germany) then using `!~` this is

```
$1 !~ /^DE\.BERLIN$/
```

whilst using `!=` this is

```
$1 != "DE.BERLIN"
```

Side note: GNU `AWK` allows you to access last column via `$NF`, if for your task you want to check if last column is not `TR` then you might harness this feature by replacing `$8 !~ /^TR$/` using `$NF != "TR"`

Comment: Thanks Daweo. There are however 8 fields:
```awk -F '\t' 'END{print NF}' out1.txt```
8

Comment: @ChristianHick you checked last row, I am wondering if it is in *all* rows?

Comment: Yes they are: ```awk -F '\t' '{print NF}' out1.txt | uniq```8

Answer (score 0):

I found what does work here. I changed `type = $8` to

```
type = ($8 = "TR" ? "" : $8)
```

This prints:

```
./trans_sop out1.txt 
DESCRIPTION 2017



EXPENSES

VARIABLE EXPENSES
Food – Groceries    -194.98
Household   -97.90
Principal & Interest    -200.00
Property – Rent -250.00
Transfers   460.00
TOTAL VARIABLE EXPENSES -282.88

TOTAL EXPENSES  -282.88



NET INCOME  -282.88
```

Comment: That would **always** assign `type` to be `""`, you could replace it with `type=""`.